# Осуществление доступа к UI-элементам из другого класса

Tags: objective-c

Конкретный код долго описывать, постараюсь написать абстрактно:

1. Есть `ViewController`, который содержит такие элементы, как `UIPickerView` и два `UITextField`.
2. Есть `PickerViewController`, в котором реализованы методы интерфейсов `UIPickerViewDelegate` и `UIPickerViewDataSource` - `didSelectRow`, `titleForRow` и другие.

Мне нужно при выборе элемента в `UIPickerView` изменять содержимое `UITextField`. На данный момент я этого сделать не могу, так как метод `didSelectRow` находится в `PickerViewController`. Доступа к `UITextField` из `ViewController` у меня нет. Как получить этот доступ? А главное как это сделать правильно?

Да и вообще, допускается ли реализовывать методы `PickerView` в другом классе или надо рядом с самим `PickerView`?

Comment: как то это странно звучит, если у вас фактически PickerViewController является дочерним у ViewController. ViewController должен иметь к нему референс

Comment: @MaxMikheyenko ViewController имеет, а вот PickerViewController к первому нет

Comment: так пусть viewController при создании PickerViewController'а (я так понимаю VC владелец PVC), передаст референс на себя

Comment: @MaxMikheyenko Вот это я и хотел выяснить. Правильно ли так передавать референс на главный ViewController?

Comment: правильно, только убедитесь, что не создаете retain cycle - в PVC референс на VC должен быть `weak`

Comment: даже не так. я так понимаю PVC это не сабкласс uiviewcontroller, а просто класс в который вы вынесли delegate и datasource?

Comment: @MaxMikheyenko Да

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть 3 способа решить задачу:

**1. Через Синглтон.**

В классе PickerViewController в методе didSelectRow передаете данные в синглтон, например так:

```
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    SingletonData.singletonDataInstance.lastSelect=[self.colorArray objectAtIndex:row];
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"gotoViewController" sender:nil];
}
```

Где colorArray - массив с данными pickerView.

Не забудьте создать Segue с переходом от PickerViewController на ViewController и идентификатором gotoViewController.

И при показе формы ViewController (когда мы возвращаемся в нее после выбора в PickerViewController) обрабатываем эти данные:

```
-(void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    if ([SingletonData.singletonDataInstance.lastSelect count]>0)
    {
        ... // Ваш код, например:
        UITextField1.text = SingletonData.singletonDataInstance.lastSelect;

        SingletonData.singletonDataInstance.lastSelect = @""; // Очищаем выбор после обработки
    }
}
```

Синглтон:

*Файл SingletonData.h*

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
@interface SingletonData : NSObject
{ 
}
@property NSString *lastSelect;
    + (SingletonData *) singletonDataInstance;
@end
```

*Файл SingletonData.m*

```
#import "SingletonData.h"
@implementation SingletonData
static SingletonData *sharedSingletonData_ = nil;
+ (SingletonData *) singletonDataInstance
{
    if (sharedSingletonData_ == nil)
    {
        sharedSingletonData_ = [[SingletonData alloc] init];
        sharedSingletonData_.lastSelect = @"";
    }
    return sharedSingletonData_;
}
@end
```

---

**2. Второй способ - передаем данные через NSNotificationCenter.**

Достоинство метода - данные передаются сразу же, и если у вас открыты обе формы одновременно (например на iPad), то первый ViewController будет обновлятся сразу же.
Недостаток - экран ViewController надо хотя бы один раз загрузить перед PickerViewController.

Подписываемся на получение данных в ViewController:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    ...
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(userSelect:) name:@"userSelect" object:nil];
    ...
}
```

Получаем данные в классе ViewController:

```
- (void)userSelect:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    NSDictionary* userInfo =[notification object];
    NSString *title=[userInfo objectForKey:@"title"];
    UITextField1.text = title;
}
```

Отправляем данные в классе PickerViewController (при выборе элемента в UIPickerView):

```
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    NSDictionary *dataDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[self.colorArray objectAtIndex:row] forKey:@"title"];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"userSelect" object:dataDict];
}
```

---

**3. Третий способ - прямая передача данных при переходе от экрана PickerViewController к ViewController:**

Создаем свойство, в которое запомним выбор пользователя в классе PickerViewController:
*Файл PickerViewController.h:*

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) NSString* lastSelectIn;
```

Создаем свойство, в которое мы передадим выбор пользователя в классе ViewController:
*Файл ViewController.h:*

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) NSString* lastSelectOut;
```

Отправляем данные в классе PickerViewController (при выборе элемента в UIPickerView):

```
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    self.lastSelectIn = [self.colorArray objectAtIndex:row];
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"gotoViewController" sender:nil];
}
```

Передаем эти данные в экран ViewController:

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.destinationViewController isKindOfClass:[ViewController class]]) {
    ViewController *vc = segue.destinationViewController;
    vc.lastSelectOut = self.lastSelectIn;
}
```

И ловим результат при перерисовке формы ViewController:

```
-(void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    if (self.lastSelectOut && [self.lastSelectOut count]>0)
    {
        ... // Ваш код, например:
        UITextField1.text = self.lastSelectOut;

        self.lastSelectOut = @""; // Очищаем выбор после обработки
    }
}
```

Не забудьте создать Segue с переходом от PickerViewController на ViewController и идентификатором gotoViewController.

> Да и вообще, допускается ли реализовывать методы PickerView в другом
>   классе или надо рядом с самим PickerView?

Допускается, вы просто должны указать какой класс является обработчиком (свойство delegate).

Comment: я бы сказал, что и синглтон и нотификейшн в этой ситуации можно смело считать антипаттернами, более того, нотификейшн скорее всего не сработает (первый контроллер должен отправить уведомление после того, как второй создан, но до того, как он появился на экране)