# Передача данных из одного ViewController в другой

Tags: ios, swift

К примеру у меня есть в каждом ViewController по одному TextField. По нажатию на кнопку осуществляется переход на другой ViewController и данные из первого TextField копируются во второй TextField

Comment: а вопрос в чем?

Comment: Если вы спрашиваете, как это сделать: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/542854/%D0%9E%D1%81%D1%83%D1%89%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%B0-%D0%BA-ui-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BC-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B0/543894#543894

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте `prepareForSegue`. Передаете строку во второй VC:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "YOURIDENTIFIER" {
        if let destinationVC = segue.destinationViewController as? SecondViewController {
            destinationVC.textToShow = firstTF.text
        }
    }
}
```

И во втором уже используете как Вам необходимо. Устанавливаете текст:

```
secondVC.text = textToShow
```